# Hard drives and partitions not showing up under files > on this computer

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

disk utility shows both internal drives yet when I look under files > other locations > on this computer, I only see one partition of one of the drives, called computer. This is after doing a fresh install where I partitioned one drive for the os, swap, and efi, and another for /home. Another strange thing I noticed is that the drive i'm using to boot is labeled dev/sdb, and the one for the home directory is labeled dev/sda. I'm a total newb when it comes to linux and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to know what partitions your system can see just use `sudo fdisk -l`.

With regard to sda/sdb etc., /dev/sd* is just Linux' way of naming partitions, but be aware that the assigned disk order can change!

I'm not sure if this answered your questions; feel free to ask something more specific.

Comment: when i fdisk -l, it's not as straight forward as I'd hope, but it seems to recognize both. But then how come they don't show up in the file manager?

Comment: As far as I know only partitions mountable by you are shown in the filemanager. You can manually configure `/etc/fstab` to change this, have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/738816/how-to-access-hard-drives-in-ubuntu-15-10 on how to do this.